# R freezes when loading pdf with multiple plots

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Im generating three plots of some data in r markdown. When Kniting the code and the pdf document appears R freezes. The plots are generated by a 1gb dataframe. Have anyone experienced this problem before?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
load("allobstot.blindern.Rda")

p1 <- qplot(allobstot.blindern$dateandtime, allobstot.blindern$air_temperature, 
geom = c("line"), xlab = "Time", ylab = "Temperature" )

p2 <- qplot(allobstot.blindern$dateandtime, allobstot.blindern$deseasonalized_air_temperature, 
geom = c("line"), xlab = "Time", ylab = "Deseasonalized Temperature" )

p3 <- qplot(allobstot.blindern$precipitation_amount, 
geom = "histogram", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Precipiation")

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: How are you using the code? You mention knitr and RMarkdown but your code uses neither.

Comment: This is the code used in markdown

Comment: This has happened to me before, and it's probably because you're trying to plot a lot of datapoints in a pdf. Since each point is an object in pdfs depending on your data you'll freeze the graphics on your computer. Try to cut your data down to a few datapoints first and see if you freeze, if you don't then it's because you're grpahing too many datapoints.

Comment: @csugai Thanks a lot. Yes, I am plotting some amount of datapoints (like 100000x3). This solved the problem!

Comment: just copied the comment into answer

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before, and it's probably because you're trying to plot a lot of datapoints in a pdf. Since each point is an object in pdfs depending on your data you'll freeze the graphics on your computer. Try to cut your data down to a few datapoints first and see if you freeze, if you don't then it's because you're grpahing too many datapoints.